# Difference time view from Excel to VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I can't obtain the average time from start to end of some activities,

I tried 1K way but the result isn't correct, every time I've one day minus.
the image can explain better (that my english).
In this example the sum of my activities il 480:52:56 hours, in vba I've different result, for vba the date is "19/01/1900  00:52:56" like 456:52:56 hous 
24 hours minus
why this difference? and how I can obtain the same result?

thanks for any suggestion

[image]

Comment: I cannot provide an answer but if I enter `?Format(0,"dd/mm/yyyy")` in the Immediate Window it gives `30/12/1899`. In an Excel cell `=TEXT(0,"dd/mm/yyyy")` gives `00/01/1900`. There is 1 day difference between these two values, 31/12/1899 is skipped. Excel and VBA have different starting points for dates. [I am aware that Excel includes 29th Feb 1900, which does not exist, but this is after the date-range in question.] We don't normally notice this discrepancy because we normally work with date differences.

Comment: If you continued to obtain the difference in hours, though, it should give you the same result.

Comment: @AndyG Do you have any resource or further information/documentation of this effect? Actually I heard of this difference between formula and VBA the first time.

Comment: @Pᴇʜ There is some information [here](http://www.cpearson.com/excel/datetime.htm) but it doesn't clearly detail the difference between Excel and VBA's starting position.

Comment: @AndyG Thank's, actually it does explain the issue. The formula calculates exactly like Lotus (including the bug Lotus had) but in VBA Microsoft implemented it correctly and the 1900-02-29 does not exist there. To make VBA as compatible as possible to the formula (for recent and future dates) they obviously decided to move the beginning of the VBA serial date value so only dates between 1900-01-01 and 1900-02-29 behave differently in their serial value (what probably was the less evil).

Comment: Who wants to show 480 hours as datetime value? If you want to convert it into number of days, use the integer part of `Range.Value2`.

Comment: @Asger Actually that is not a question of wanting that, it is the question what Excel does if you enter `480:52:56` this will automatically in a datetime value which represents `1900-01-20 00:52:56`. So that's Excel's default behaviour. What the OP could do is using something like `=INT(A1) & " days " & TEXT(A1,"hh:mm:ss")` to display it like `20 days 00:52:56`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

thanks to your comments I understand that the problem is for the minor dates of March 1, 1900 so I changed the select from:

```
Select [DataAttesa] as Data, avg(iif([totHours] > 1 and [totHours] < 61, dateadd("d",-1,CDate([totHours])) , [totHours])) as nr FROM [db_In$] Where TypeTrasp  = "AOG" group by [DataAttesa] Order by [DataAttesa]asc
```

now, when I put the recordset.results on excel the value are correct.
Thank at all

Answer (score 0):

Dates are stored as serial numbers where first valid date has a value of 1. This value in excel reads as `01/01/1900`, and in VBA as `31/12/1899`. In excel, value 60 returns `29/02/1900` which doesn't exist in VBA, so from value 61 onwards all values will return the same date in VBA and excel.

/e: Also, maximum value is 2958465 (31/12/9999), values higher than that will return error rather than valid date

Comment: Actually I can confirm this. All dates before `1900-03-01` do **not** return the same serial value (in VBA compared to formula) and therefore have to be handled very carefully.